# SingleEmailMessage Limitation in developer and in production Environment

Tags: apex, email, limits, massemailmessage, singleemailmessage

Good day everyone,

I am using `SingleEmailMessage` in developer and it seems that there is a limit of emails that can be sent. I just want to know if is it still limited in the production environment ? What is the difference of developer and production environment when it comes to sending single email.

Please help. Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [document](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm):

> In Developer Edition organizations and organizations evaluating
>   Salesforce during a trial period, your organization can send mass
>   email to no more than 10 external email addresses per day. This lower
>   limit does not apply if your organization was created before the
>   Winter '12 release and already had mass email enabled with a higher
>   limit. Additionally, your organization can send single emails to a
>   maximum of 15 email addresses per day.

Production with non-trial license, emails can be number of user licenses multiplied by 1,000, up to a daily maximum of 1,000,000

[Email Governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#email_limits_section)

Comment: Thanks friend. How will I know if my production environment has non-trial license ? And what about those production without non-trial licence what are their limitation?

Comment: Non-trial means, you have purchased licenses from salesforce for a year subscription. Non-trial means, you have spun a org with trial limit of 30 to 90 days and you didn't need to contact Salesforce account person for it. @Hope